# PhpMyAdmin (on ubuntu lamp): Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

My mysql password = '' i try to login to PhpMyAdmin (on Ubuntu 10.04 lamp) and get error:
 **Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)**
What should i do for enter to phpMyAdmin without set password?
Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can turn on the option AllowNoPassword on file /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php.

Edit the file config.inc.php, search and uncomment this line:

**// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;**

Then you can access PhpMyAdmin without password.

Comment: This command can help (tested on Ubuntu 10.04):

sed '/^    .*AllowNoPassword.*/ s/\/\///' /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php > /tmp/conf.tmp && mv /tmp/conf.tmp /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Comment: Thanks, I make that, after that i restart apache and mysql but i still get: 
Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Comment: I also run:
sudo sed '/^ .*AllowNoPassword.*/ s/\/\///' /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php > /tmp/conf.tmp && mv /tmp/conf.tmp /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
but i get:
mv: try to overwrite `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php', overriding mode 0644 (rw-r--r--)? y
mv: cannot move `/tmp/conf.tmp' to `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php': Permission denied

Comment: Try to get root before run the command. Execute: sudo -s and then the sed command. Finally, ajust the permissions: chmod 640 /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php && chown root:www-data /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Comment: I don't believe this solution works anymore in Ubuntu 14.04. I edited `/etc/phpymyadmin/config.inc.php` to uncomment/enable that line, run `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`, refresh the website, try and login with root and no password and the `AllowNoPassword` error continues to occur.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works in 14.04

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I have noticed from attempting to solve this problem.
what I went through:

1. I set $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
2. I go to phpmyadmin and login fine without password ..No problem

Then I wanted to run apache with a different user than www-data so I

- I go to /etc/apache2/eenvvars and I edit export
  APACHE_RUN_USER=myuser and export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=myuser

I restart apache2 and when I try to login to phpmyadmin without password it does not let me event though, as I previously mentioned, I set $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE.

To resolve it

- I go to  /etc/phpmyadmin/
- check the permission (run ls-l)
- I notice that it is root:www-data for config-db.php and for config.inc.php
- I run sudo chown root:myuser
- Restart apache
- Then go to phpmyadmin and login with passowrd...It works

If you run apache with a different other than www-data (i.e you own) and your config.inc.php and config-db.php are owned by www-data, then phpmyadmin will not

Comment: Thanks! The file now being chowed to the www-data user was the problem I had, great help!

Answer (score 3):

use Sudo to access the following file that mention above (etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php.) and also stop apcaha before editing this file with this

> // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

else it will wont allow you to update it. 
Command for stopping apcahe

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

hope it will help it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Open `phpmyadmin` config file

```
sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
     * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```